# Multiple events, one function

Tags: javascript, html

The following works with no problem:

```
element.oninput = go;
element.onchange = go;
...
```

But isn't there a shorter way to achieve the same result? Do we have to repeat the same line for each event?

Comment: `element.oninput = element.onchange = go;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript (along with quite a few other languages), an assignment operation (`L=R`) returns `R` as the result.

Therefore, `element.oninput = element.onchange = go` should do what you're looking for, since `element.onchange = go` returns `go`, which is then assigned to `element.oninput`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! `onchange` is added to support IE and `oninput` for other browsers to handle an `<input type="range">`. Does the events order make any difference?

Comment: It shouldn't. /length

Answer (score 0):

if using jQuery , that will be easy. eg:

```
 $(element).bind('input change', go);
```

Comment: Please look at the question tag `JavaScript`.

Comment: @Hermes Thanks for the warning. It won't happen again.